# can LISTAGG be used in view?

Tags: oracle

I have a sql statement that works properly and yields proper result.

```
SELECT "StoreId",  LISTAGG("ProductCategory"
                          || ':'
                          || '('
                          || ProductIds
                          || ')', ', ') WITHIN GROUP (
ORDER BY "ProductCategory") AS ProductsAndCategories
FROM
  (SELECT "StoreId",
    "ProductCategory",
    LISTAGG("ProductId", ',') WITHIN GROUP (
  ORDER BY "ProductId") AS ProductIds
  FROM SUPERMARKET
  GROUP BY "StoreId",
    "ProductCategory"
  ) s
GROUP BY "StoreId";
```

However, if I use the exact same statement and put it in View, I got a compiler error that does not quite make sense (see below). Someone told me that it works as there is no limitation on using LISTAGG with view, but it clearly errors out on me. I am not sure what is wrong with my statement. Could someone point it out to me?

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question and show the `create view` statement.  You can also try as `create view <name> as` before the query.

Comment: I have used `listagg` in a view... so it is definitely possible. Just need to work out why your case fails!

Comment: @Gordon: You do not believe this! I can create the view using the exact same statement that caused problem when I used the GUI! If I create the view using statement, it works! Can you please put in the answer so that I can give proper credit to you? I am new to Oracle and thought it would be easier to use the GUI but obviously it has bug!!!! Thank you so much for your help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem appears to be with the GUI.

You can create a view using:

```
create view v_storeproducts as
    SELECT "StoreId", 
            LISTAGG("ProductCategory"
                              || ':'
                              || '('
                              || ProductIds
                              || '
                   )', ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "ProductCategory") AS ProductsAndCategories
    FROM (SELECT "StoreId",
                 "ProductCategory",
                  LISTAGG("ProductId", ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "ProductId") AS ProductIds
          FROM SUPERMARKET
          GROUP BY "StoreId",
          "ProductCategory"
         ) s
    GROUP BY "StoreId";
```